# Find the initial value of the signal from its Laplace transform?

Tags: laplace-transform

Given

[image]

My answer:

[image]

.[image]
,
Since there is an impulse at the origin, the initial value theorem cannot be applied. Is this conclusion correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be surprised to find that there are inverse laplace transform calculators on the web. Here is your problem and solution: -

[image]

It looks like your answer is correct. For an impulse, the answer is the inverse transform of the transfer function.

[Calculator link](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/inverse-laplace-calculator/inverse%20laplace%20%5Cfrac%7B4s%20%2B%205%7D%7B2s%2B1%7D)

Comment: @305k Than you. Can I conclude that when the LT of a signal is not strictly proper, We cannot apply the initial value theorem?

Comment: Dunno @LelouchYagami - it's been years (well several decades) since I did this.

Answer (score 0):

An impulse has infinite height and zero width at t=0, which would be consistent with the Laplace initial value theorem.